# Casting custom view on inflated View

Tags: android, view, casting

I have layout like this

pie_chart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/piechart"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#F00"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

I'm trying to cast PieChart type into View I inflated. I'm using MPAndroidchart for graphs. PieChart's parent classes extend VieGroup, so I assume Casting PieChart type onto View should be correct, but this is giving me an error.

Code which causing the problem:

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);

    View pieView =  View.inflate(AppContext.context, R.layout.pie_chart,(ViewGroup)view);
    PieChart pieChart= (PieChart) pieView;

    return view;
}
```

LogCat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                                                                   at com.teltonika.rms.fragment.OverviewFragment.onCreateView(OverviewFragment.java:31)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1998)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:709)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: show me this PieChart   class what you extend ?

Comment: @sushantgosavi I can't its from MPAndroidCharts library

Comment: Please explain why you downvote my question. It's constructed according to rules and I beleive is quite reasonable

Comment: @VygintasB wait.I dont no why user do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be
>   cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart

A **ClassCastException** is thrown by Java when you try to cast an Object of one data type to another.

**Problem Starts from**

```
 PieChart pieChart= (PieChart) pieView; // Don't do this
```

**Try this way**

```
View pieView =  View.inflate(AppContext.context, R.layout.pie_chart,(ViewGroup)view);
PieChart pieChart= (PieChart) pieView.findViewById(R.id.piechart);
```

Comment: I thought my inflated view is added to fragment's layout and View.inflate() returned my inflated view's refference. Can you comment on this?

Comment: @VygintasB i guess `View pieView =  View.inflate(AppContext.context` create problem

Comment: After a little bit of research found out that if I supply root view for View.inflate() method, it will return new root View with my inflated view, but if I add null for View.inflate() method it will return my inflated view only

Comment: @VygintasB yessss. You can posted this as answer

Answer (score 5):

After a little bit of research I found out that if I supply root View for View.inflate() method, it will return new root View with my inflated view, but if I add null for View.inflate() method it will return my inflated view only.

E.G

This will return `Linearlayout` because `view` root view is LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout pieView =  View.inflate(AppContext.context, R.layout.pie_chart,(ViewGroup)view);
```

but if I add null it will inflate View I'm providing. For this case It's Piechart

```
PieChart pieView =  View.inflate(AppContext.context, R.layout.pie_chart,null);
```

Comment: Yes yes .Thanks for share

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);

    View pieView =  View.inflate(AppContext.context, R.layout.pie_chart,(ViewGroup)view);
    PieChart pieChart= (PieChart) pieView.findViewById(R.id.piechart);

    return view;
}
```

You were just casting your fragment view to PieChart because of which you are getting this error.